# Google Font file size download vs CDN

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I would like to use the [Font "Anton"](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Anton?selection.family=Anton) which google provides via API but also available to download. When I use it like so

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet">
```

the browser request 1kb and a sec later 14kb from `google.gstatic`. When I want to download the file and host it on my own server, the file size is suddenly 80kb. Can somebody explain to me where the difference is comming from and how i can reduce it? the downloaded version is `.ttf` while the cdn is `.woff2`. can I download and implement the `woff2` version like so?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Anton';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Anton Regular'), local('Anton-Regular'), url(myServerPathToFile.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Im not really familiar with the different font file types, can somebody clear out where risks/losses could appear when using `woff2` compared to `ttf` and where the different sizes come from?

Comment: Please reffer this link : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp

Comment: Google will probably check, wich browser you use. That is because `WOFF2` is — not — supported by `IE11`. Just use the https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator. To get `WOFF` and `WOFF2`.

Comment: It's best to use the cdn as it means you can process more request from your server as there is one less request to files on your server (so the page loads faster).  Also I'm sure there is some sort of license that says you should use the cdn. As for the woff2 file - different browsers need different file types which is why you include all the other types, not all browsers have been updated to use woff2 so I would recommend you carry on using all types, unless you are not bothered about all browsers using that font